# Regular Expression limiting match only for "." difficulties

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing a app for WP7 and using this for my RegEx

`new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D\.{1}");`

Basically I want user to input only numeric data with one `.` allowed for `double`, it works when user inputs only 1 period but app crashes as soon as another period is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally not use Regular Expressions for this.

```
bool isInputGood(string input) {
    double d;
    return double.TryParse(input, out d);
}
```

Of course, this won't reject something like `123.456.789`, but it WILL accept something like `123.456 e+5`

Comment: I agree (and I did suggest to use `double.TryParse()` a few minutes ago... as well ;-) )

Comment: As is usual, there's a race condition in StackOverflow. Posting answers isn't very thread-safe ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s*$");
```

This checks the whole string (anchored with `^` and `$`) and matches "legitimate" numbers.

Note that this is not a suitable check to be used in applications which may run on different regional settings, as the decimal separator may vary. Why not check the input by doing a `double.TryParse()` instead?

Comment: With this the app crashes even if a single `.` is used and I want input only for numeric data.

Comment: Define "crash". You asked for only one dot, which is what it matches. But I'll edit it to restrict it to digits as well... ;-)

Comment: By crash I mean the app just closes and shows an error in debugger.